# Substitution substrings from a key-value table

Tags: python, regex, string, substring, substitution

Given a multi-char to single char string translation table:

```
>>> telex_mappings
{'eer': 'ể', 'awj': 'ặ', 'Dd': 'Đ', 'Ooj': 'Ộ', 'oox': 'ỗ', 'Aas': 'Ấ', 'Eej': 'Ệ', 'awx': 'ẵ', 'eef': 'ề', 'oo': 'ô', 'aas': 'ấ', 'Aax': 'Ẫ', 'owr': 'ở', 'Uws': 'Ớ', 'Awj': 'Ặ', 'Oor': 'Ổ', 'Awf': 'Ằ', 'ows': 'ớ', 'aaj': 'ậ', 'Owj': 'Ợ', 'aa': 'â', 'eex': 'ễ', 'Oox': 'Ỗ', 'Owr': 'Ở', 'awf': 'ằ', 'Aa': 'Â', 'aw': 'ă', 'awr': 'ẳ', 'uwj': 'ợ', 'uwx': 'ỡ', 'owj': 'ợ', 'Awx': 'Ẵ', 'Uwr': 'Ở', 'Aaj': 'Ậ', 'Eex': 'Ễ', 'Awr': 'Ẳ', 'Uw': 'Ư', 'Eef': 'Ề', 'aaf': 'ầ', 'Aws': 'Ắ', 'ees': 'ế', 'Ee': 'Ê', 'Ow': 'Ơ', 'Ees': 'Ế', 'Owx': 'Ỡ', 'Eer': 'Ể', 'Aar': 'Ẩ', 'Oo': 'Ô', 'uwf': 'ờ', 'uw': 'ư', 'uws': 'ớ', 'owx': 'ỡ', 'ow': 'ơ', 'aar': 'ẩ', 'eej': 'ệ', 'oof': 'ờ', 'ee': 'ê', 'uwr': 'ở', 'Aw': 'Ă', 'ooj': 'ộ', 'Aaf': 'Ầ', 'aax': 'ẫ', 'Oof': 'Ờ', 'oor': 'ổ', 'aws': 'ắ', 'Oos': 'Ớ', 'Uwf': 'Ờ', 'Uwx': 'Ỡ', 'dd': 'đ', 'oos': 'ố', 'Uwj': 'Ợ'}

>>> telex_mappings['eef']
'ề'
>>> telex_mappings['aaf']
'ầ'
>>> telex_mappings['uw']
'ư'
```

And the input string:

```
>>> s = 'Nguyeefn Traafn Anh Thuw'
```

The desired function would be something like:

```
>>> func('Nguyeefn Traafn Anh Thuw')
'Nguyên Trân Anh Thư'
```

I've tried:

```
>>> s = 'Nguyeefn Traafn Anh Thuw'
>>> for k,v in telex_mappings.items():
...     s = s.replace(k, v)
... 
>>> s
'Nguyền Trâfn Anh Thư'
```

But we see that there is a key for 'aa' which causes the replacement to take place first before 'aaf'. Ideally, the longer keys should be replaced first.

**How should the replacement be such that it's possible to substitute substrings from a key-value table starting from the longest key onwards?**

**Is there some sort of regex methods instead of iterating through all key-value pairs in the mapping?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible regex solution:

```
import re

pattern= '|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in sorted(telex_mappings, key=len, reverse=True))
result= re.sub(pattern, lambda match:telex_mappings[match.group()], s)
```

This sorts the dictionary keys by length, then creates a regex pattern of the form `key1|key2|key3|...`, and finally substitutes all occurrences of this pattern with the corresponding dict value.

Comment: Would `lambda match: telex_mappings[match.group(0)]` be the same?

Comment: @alvas [Yes, it defaults to `group(0)`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group)

Comment: Thans @Rawing! Then I guess `telex_mapping.get(m.group(0), m.group(0))` would be good to avoid the KeyError =)

Comment: I don't see how this could ever produce a KeyError. The regex pattern is created from the dict keys after all.

Comment: Ah, yes yes, it's different from retrieving a separate hand-written regex! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 4):

Sort `telex_mappings` keys by length descending:

```
for k in sorted(telex_mappings, key=len, reverse=True):
    s = s.replace(k, telex_mappings[k])
```

Comment: You can drop `.keys()`